# Is there any difference between insert data into database with local procedure or function with recent frameworks like spring or entity framework?

Tags: java, c#, .net, oracle, plsql

I want to insert my data into the database. I think two solutions can do my job.
the first way is that I create my procedure or function into the database and call them with parameters that I passed to them in .Net or Java programming language.
the other way is I use entity framework or other technology to insert my data into the database.
what are advantages and disadvantages?
actually, I want to know which solution has better performance and integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very broad question, but basically it boils down to: unless you are talking about really small projects, with a very limited life time or "pure education purpose", you should rather rely on a framework.

Thing is: getting data to/from a database is

- **harder** than you think it is, and
- basically a "solved" problem.

When you start to re-invent the wheel, you will repeat the same mistakes that thousands of people made before you. You might not even notice that you made a mistake, until some attacker uses SQL injection, corrupting or stealing data. And assuming your project attracts users, and grows over time, so will your requirements. And you will be constantly adding features to your "own framework", making it more and more complex.

Using a "good" framework prevents you from all (well, most) of that.

So even when spring looks "too big" for you today, it would be able to "grow" with you over time.

Beyond that: when performance becomes an issue, then because the overall design of your application is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences.
Stored procedure can use cached execution plans, so there is chance for better performance. Yes, there may occur some problems with this approach (parameter sniffing, SQL injection...). But generally, I would say stored procedure performs better than code executed from application scope (EF, NHibernate, ...).

Inserting from ORM (e.g. Entity Framework) is easier, you can benefit from type checking so compiler will help you from writing typos in property names and so on.

So for projects where the performance is not the top priority I would go for ORM and for other projects I would pick mix of them: writing stored procedure and call it using ORM.